# Laravel test using PHPUnit update data, Failed asserting that two strings are equal

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I was trying to learn PHPUnit on laravel and I got a little problem. I managed to make a test for data input and data validation but for updating the data somehow it didn't work.

This is my update function in controller

```
public function update(PostRequest $request, PostModel $post)
    {

        $update = $request->all();

        $update['category_id'] = $request->category;

        $post->update($update);

        $post->TagModels()->sync($request->tag);

        session()->flash('success', 'Update Post Success');

        return redirect('post');
    }
```

This my route for update

```
Route::patch('post/{post:slug}/update', 'PostController@update');
```

This my test for update

```
public function test_post_update()
    {
        // $this->withoutExceptionHandling();

        $data = factory(PostModel::class)->make();

        $response = $this->post('post/store', [
            'title'=> $data->title,

            'body'=> $data->body,

            'category'=> $data->category_id,

            'tag'=> [rand(1, 5)],
        ]);

        $post = PostModel::first()->slug;

        // $data2 = factory(PostModel::class)->make();

        $this->patch('post/'.$post.'/update', [
            'title'=> 'update',

            'body'=> $data->body,

            'category'=> $data->category_id,

            'tag'=> [rand(1, 5)],
        ]);

        $data->refresh();

        $this->assertEquals('update', PostModel::first()->title);
    }
```

I always get the following error

```
> Executing task: c:/xampp/htdocs/my-app-test/vendor/bin/phpunit.bat c:/xampp/htdocs/my-app-test/tests/Unit/PostTest.php --filter '^.*::test_post_update' <

PHPUnit 8.5.9 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

F                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 334 ms, Memory: 24.00 MB

There was 1 failure:

1) Tests\Unit\PostTest::test_post_update
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'update'
+'Laudantium voluptatibus voluptatem ipsam sit.'

C:\xampp\htdocs\my-app-test\tests\Unit\PostTest.php:216

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
```

Please tell me where I went wrong in my code.

New error after i uncomment `$this->withoutExceptionHandling();`

This the new error

```
1) Tests\Unit\PostTest::test_post_update
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'post_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `post_tag` (`post_id`, `tag_id`) values (?, 1))
```

Comment: Do you have `title` in `$fillable` inside `PostModel`?

Comment: yes i have title in $fillable inside PostModel `protected $fillable = ['title', 'slug', 'body', 'category_id'];`

Answer (score 0):

Try to tweak the update method to deal with all request data fields except `tags` and `category`

```php
public function update(PostRequest $request, PostModel $post)

{

    //(dd($request->all());

    //authorise the logged in user to perform the update

    //Validate the request data


    $post->category_id = $request->category;

    $post->update($request->except(['category', 'tags']));

    $post->TagModels()->sync($request->tag);

    session()->flash('success', 'Update Post Success');

    return redirect('post');
}
```

Let us tweak the test a little

```php
ublic function test_post_update()
    {
        // $this->withoutExceptionHandling();

        $data = factory(PostModel::class)->make();

        $response = $this->post('post/store', [
            'title'=> $data->title,

            'body'=> $data->body,

            'category'=> $data->category_id,

            'tag'=> [rand(1, 5)],
        ]);

        $post = PostModel::first();

        // $data2 = factory(PostModel::class)->make();

        $this->patch('post/' . $post->slug . '/update', [
            'title'=> 'update',

            'body'=> $data->body,

            'category'=> $data->category_id,

            'tag'=> [rand(1, 5)],
        ]);

        $post->refresh();

        $this->assertEquals('update', $post->title);
    }
```

Comment: fow the authorize  i have used `use WithoutMiddleware;` in my code and for your suggestion it didn't work

Comment: Okay if you are bypassing the authorisation for the time being. With the change in code for the update method when you run the test again what is the error/failure message

Comment: After you modify the update method code with the one I have given here in answer, when you run the test again what is the error/failure message

Comment: after i modify the update method, the error i get is same, there are other suggestions.

Comment: Try to `dd($request->all()` as updated in my answer by uncommenting the dd() statement. What is the value that you get for $request->title

Comment: Are you validating the data in `PostRequest`? Against what rules are you validating (if so)?

Comment: after i `dd($request->all())` i get `"title" => "update"` That's weird.

Comment: this the validation `'title'=> ['required', 'min:3'],

            'body'=>'required',

            'category'=> 'required',

            'tag'=> ['required', 'array'],`

Comment: sorry but your second suggestion it didn't work and the error still same.